# solve $\sqrt{x+7}<x$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, quadratics

> solve $\sqrt{x+7}<x$

I tried $\sqrt{x+7}<x\\
x+7<x^2\\
x^2-x-7>0\\
x\in \left(-\infty, \dfrac{1-\sqrt{29}}{2}\right) \cup \left( \dfrac{1+\sqrt{29}}{2},+\infty\right) $

I m not sure, if this is correct method and if the solution is correct .

I look for a simple and short way.

I have studied maths up to $12$th grade.Thanks.

Comment: Note that when you square both sides of an inequality, it only remains true if both sides were positive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, we need to have $x+7\ge 0$.

Then, note that $\sqrt{x+7}$ is non-negative. So, since we have
$$0\le\sqrt{x+7}\lt x,$$
we have
$$0\lt x.$$

Hence, we have
$$x+7\ge0\ \ \ \text{and}\ \ \ x+7\lt x^2\ \ \ \text{and}\ \ \ 0\lt x.$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

Note that $\sqrt{x+7}$ is a real number only if $x+7\ge 0$ and, in this case,$\sqrt{x+7}$ is a positive number so that we must have $x \ge 0$.

From all these conditions you find :
$$
\sqrt{x+7}>0 \iff 
\begin {cases}
x\ge 0\\
x+7<x^2
\end{cases}
$$